# Trying to add row with foriegn key in typeOrm

Tags: database, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to add a row to the table customer address with a foreign key customer. The calling function is as below:

```
async createAddress(customerId,createAddressDto:CreateAddressDto){
    const customer = await this.customerRepository.findOne(customerId);
    // console.log(customer);
    
    const saveAddress  = {
            customer: customer,
            addressLine1: createAddressDto.addressLine1,
            addressLine2: createAddressDto.addressLine2,
            city: createAddressDto.city,
            state: createAddressDto.state,
            alias: createAddressDto.alias,
            latLong: createAddressDto.latLong,
            isDeleted: false
      }
    const cAddress: CAddress = this.cAddressRepository.create(saveAddress);
    await this.customerRepository.save(cAddress);
    return 'success'
  }
```

the entities of customer and customer address is as below:

```
@Entity({ name: 'c_address' })
export class CAddress {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    city: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    state: string;
   
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    addressLine1: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    addressLine2: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    latLong: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    alias: string;

    @Column({
        nullable: true,
        default : false
     })
    isDeleted: boolean;    

    @ManyToOne(type => Customer, customer => customer.address) 
    customer : Customer; 
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'customers' })
export class Customer {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({nullable: false})
    name : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    phoneNumber : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    email : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    DOB : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    age : number    
    
    @Column({nullable: true})
    gender : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    companyName : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    GSTIN : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    totalSales : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    totalOrders : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    lastPurchaseDate : Date

    @Column({nullable: true})
    primaryStoreId : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    firstPurchaseDate : Date

    @Column({nullable: true})
    userName : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    referalUser : string

    @Column({default: false})
    isLoyal : boolean

    @Column({nullable: true})
    walletBalance : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    dateIsLoyal : Date

    @Column({nullable: true})
    dateNotLoyal : Date

    @Column({nullable: true})
    lastSuperOfferBought : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    fbToken : string

    @Column({nullable: true})
    appAddDate : Date

    @Column({nullable: true})
    changeFile : string

    @OneToMany(type => CAddress, caddress => caddress.customer) 
    address: CAddress[]; 
}
```

I am getting an error while trying to add an entry to the address table like so -

[image]

Is there any other way I can design the calling function? maybe use a query builder? where I can add the customer as a relation to customer-address.

Any help is dearly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Please add the errors as code. Your image of error is unavailable now.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Hey @Jonas, yes I did see your answer but the issue with my code was a simple mistake that I made, I just had to change this line in the async function `await this.customerRepository.save(cAddress);` to this `await this.cAddressRepository.save(cAddress);` a simple mistake. Nonetheless thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the join column on the address entity

```js
    @ManyToOne(type => Customer, customer => customer.address)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'customer_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' }) 
    customer: Customer;
```

If you want to be able to create it with the repository API `.save` command, then you need to define it with `cascade` as well.

```js
    @ManyToOne(type => Customer, customer => customer.address,    
    {
      cascade: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'customer_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' }) 
    customer: Customer;
```

now you can

```js
   user.addresses = addressEntities
   user.save()
```